# handling ios device orientation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uideviceorientation

I am having issues with my uiviews depending on the devices orientation...

The main issue that I am having is that

```
UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp
UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
```

are messing with my view I only want to support Portrait and landscape (left right) so if the device changes orientation my view alters itself correctly..

this is what I have implemented at the moment. Basicly its a UIView that scrolls up from the bottom of the screen and has several buttons in this view that the user is able to select to load a different view.

```
#pragma jumpBarButtons
- (void)jumpBarButtonPosition
{

    //orientation stuff
    if (jumpBar.isViewLoaded) {

        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];


        switch (orientation) {
            case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            {
                NSLog(@"Portrait");

                // Row one
                jumpButton1.frame = CGRectMake(18.45, 23.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton2.frame = CGRectMake(93.9, 23.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton3.frame = CGRectMake(169.35, 23.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton4.frame = CGRectMake(244.8, 23.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                // Row tow
                jumpButton5.frame = CGRectMake(18.45, 95.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton6.frame = CGRectMake(93.9, 95.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton7.frame = CGRectMake(169.35, 95.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton8.frame = CGRectMake(244.8, 95.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                // Row three
                jumpButton9.frame = CGRectMake(18.45, 167.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton10.frame = CGRectMake(93.9, 167.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton11.frame = CGRectMake(169.35, 167.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton12.frame = CGRectMake(244.8, 167.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                // Row four
                jumpButton13.frame = CGRectMake(18.45, 239.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton14.frame = CGRectMake(93.9, 239.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton15.frame = CGRectMake(169.35, 239.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton16.frame = CGRectMake(244.8, 239.0, 57.0, 57.0);
            }
                break;

case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            {
                viewSpaceHeight = 207;
                viewSpaceWidth = 480;

                // Row one
                jumpButton1.frame = CGRectMake(19.7, 9.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton2.frame = CGRectMake(96.42, 9.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton3.frame = CGRectMake(173.13, 9.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton4.frame = CGRectMake(249.84, 9.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton5.frame = CGRectMake(326.55, 9.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton6.frame = CGRectMake(403.26, 9.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                // Row tow
                jumpButton7.frame = CGRectMake(19.7, 75.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton8.frame = CGRectMake(96.42, 75.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton9.frame = CGRectMake(173.13, 75.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton10.frame = CGRectMake(249.84, 75.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton11.frame = CGRectMake(326.55, 75.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton12.frame = CGRectMake(403.26, 75.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                // Row three
                jumpButton13.frame = CGRectMake(19.7, 141.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton14.frame = CGRectMake(96.42, 141.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton15.frame = CGRectMake(173.13, 141.0, 57.0, 57.0);
                jumpButton16.frame = CGRectMake(249.84, 141.0, 57.0, 57.0);

            }
                break;
//..
```

thats pretty much it if in portrait there are 16 4,4,4,4 icons, if landscape then the icons are 6,6,4. what happens if the device is flipped faceup or facedown, all of these button views disappear..  what can I do to stop this, any help would be gretly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UIInterfaceDirection` instead. Its part of the [`UIApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class and it contains only the following values

```
typedef enum {
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
} UIInterfaceOrientation;
```

You can easily check your current orientation like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]
```

Comment: ahhh perfect! thankyou very much.. I though I was going crazy for a sec! :P