# How to make screen scrollable when orientation is landscape xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios5

Hi all I'm developing an app in xcode for iPhone. i've many label in that it looks good when orientation is Portrait but when it is landscape all labels will overlap on each other, so i want to make it as scrollable screen only when it is in landscape mode. please help me Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is this iOS?  If so tag it 'ios'.

Comment: hundreds of questions asked for this, have you googled the issue, also this is quite wide question. check out these threads - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696819/orientation-handling-in-interface-builder, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075600/handling-ios-device-orientation

Comment: ya it is. I'm developing on ios5

Answer (score 0):

Add **UIScrollView** in self.view.

Now set frame of yourScrollView according to orientation and its content size according to it. But in protrait frame and  content size will be equal so there will be no scrolling.

Now in landscape, frame and  content size will be not be equal so there will be scrolling

**Note** : Adjust UIlements's fame according to orientation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

  if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
  {
     [yourScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
     [yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,460)];
     //change frame of UIELement(labels) here according to orientation
  }
  else
  {
     [yourScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,480,300)];
     [yourScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480,460)];
     //change frame of UIELement(labels) here according to orientation
  }
  return YES;
}
```